# Inverse of Complex Matrix using Apache Commons

Tags: java, matrix, apache-commons-math

Currently in the process of converting some `Matlab Code` over to `Java w/ the Apache Commons library`.

How would I go about inverting a `complex matrix`? My usual method of creating a `LUDecomposition object` on the matrix and calling `getSolver()` doesn't seem to work, the Solver doesn't accept `Field Matrices`.

Comment: Try FieldLUDecomposition https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/FieldLUDecomposition.html